# Weird Â symbol after every word in database

Tags: microsoft-word, symbols

I can't figure out what this Â symbol is.  I have a webpage with some textboxes that allow users to submit info to a database. A few of the users are copying and pasting sentences from Microsoft Word.  Could it be Word that is inserting these?

[image]

Comment: It is supposedly a non-breaking space (nbsp): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-%C3%82-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an encoding issue.  UTF-8 will correctly display a non-breaking space `&nbsp;` rather than displaying `Â`.

Add the following code inside `<head></head>` to indicate the webpage is UTF-8.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```